# Wcf - Get Request and Response with System.Diagnostics

Tags: c#, wcf, tracelistener

.
Hello

I have a WCF and I have to record the request and the associated response.

Today I seem to get the request and response, but I have no ID to associate.

Using the following configuration in .config:

```xml
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
    <add name="xml" type="Ctx_Host.WebTraceListener, Ctx_Host" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
          logEntireMessage="true"
          logMalformedMessages="false"
          logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
          maxMessagesToLog="300000"
          maxSizeOfMessageToLog="200000"/>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And the .cs code is :

```
public class WebTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"F:\wcf\log.csv", true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }


    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"F:\wcf\log.csv", true))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you tell me if it is possible to link the request and response in this way or another?

thanks for your help

Comment: The diagnostics generates a "Correlation ActivityID" in messages, it's the same and relation requests and responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagnostics generates a "Correlation ActivityID" in messages, it's the same and relation requests and responses.

This link has more information about and can help you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392926/Grouping-application-traces-using-ActivityId

And this about ActivityID:

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Propagating_the_ActivityId_to_a_WCF_service.aspx